# Entity Framework Core on SQL Server: Failing to delete an optionally self-referenced record

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreign-keys, entity-framework-core

Given a database, tracking persons and their optional spouse as self referencing foreign key:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? SpouseId { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framwork Core DbContext looks like this, notice the `DeleteBehavior.SetNull`:

```
public class PersonsContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonsContext(DbContextOptions<PersonsContext> options) : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(typeof(Person))
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(typeof(Person), nameof(Person.SpouseId))
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
    }
}
```

This does not even generate a model. The error says:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Persons_Persons_SpouseId' on 
>   table 'Persons' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify 
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN 
>   KEY constraints.

---

Okay, second attempt. We're taking care of breaking the reference on our own. The FK will be modelled with `DeleteBehavior.Restrict`:

```
public class PersonsContext : DbContext
{
    public PersonsContext(DbContextOptions<PersonsContext> options) : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(typeof(Person))
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(typeof(Person), nameof(Person.SpouseId))
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

A simple test tries to null out the reference on both sides, and then deletes a married person, leaving the other person without a `SpouseId`:

```
[Fact]
public void Manually_Remove_Reference()
{
    using (var personsContext = new PersonsContext(DbContextOptions))
    {
        var him = new Person {Id = 1, Name = "Him", SpouseId = 2};
        var her = new Person {Id = 2, Name = "Her", SpouseId = 1};

        personsContext.Persons.Add(him);
        personsContext.Persons.Add(her);
        personsContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var personsContext = new PersonsContext(DbContextOptions))
    {
        var him = personsContext.Persons.Find(1);
        var her = personsContext.Persons.Find(2);
        him.SpouseId = null;
        her.SpouseId = null;
        personsContext.Persons.Remove(him);
        personsContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var personsContext = new PersonsContext(DbContextOptions))
    {
        Assert.Null(personsContext.Find<Person>(1));
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'ForeignKey: Person {'SpouseId'} -> Person {'Id'} Unique, ForeignKey: Person {'SpouseId'} -> Person {'Id'} Unique'.

Stack Trace:

```
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.Multigraph`2.BatchingTopologicalSort(Func`2 formatCycle)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.TopologicalSort(IEnumerable`1 commands)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.<BatchCommands>d__8.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(Tuple`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entries)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Persistence.Tests.UnitTest1.Manually_Remove_Reference() in C:\Users\MarcWittke\source\scratchpad\Persistence\Persistence.Tests\UnitTest1.cs:line 58
```

Adding more `SaveChanges()` after nulling the references doesn't make a difference. WHat indeed works, is: breaking the reference in a separate DbContext instance, saving it, opening a new one and deleting the record. But this won't be atomic any more.

Full code: https://github.com/marcwittke/DeletingOptionallySelfReferencedRecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the issue was my test setup, inserting the two persons. (note to myself: check line numbers in stack traces)

this code works as expected:

```
[Fact]
public void Manually_Remove_Reference()
{
    using (var personsContext = new PersonsContext(DbContextOptions))
    {
        var him = new Person { Name = "Him"};
        var her = new Person { Name = "Her"};

        personsContext.Persons.Add(him);
        personsContext.Persons.Add(her);
        personsContext.SaveChanges();

        // this must occur after inserting the two persons!!
        him.SpouseId = her.Id;
        her.SpouseId = him.Id;
        personsContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var personsContext = new PersonsContext(DbContextOptions))
    {
        var her = personsContext.Persons.Find(2);
        her.SpouseId = null;

        var him = personsContext.Persons.Find(1);
        personsContext.Persons.Remove(him);
        personsContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    using (var personsContext = new PersonsContext(DbContextOptions))
    {
        Assert.Null(personsContext.Find<Person>(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one EnityState can be assigned to a tracked entity at any given time. So when you are setting `him.SpouseId == null` that entity has a state of `EntityState.Modified`, but as soon as you call `personsContext.Remove(him)` the state is now `EntityState.Deleted`. EF won't track order of state changes in this manner, only the current state of the entity.

To fix your issue you must call `.SaveChanges()` as soon as you modify the FK fields to null, then remove the entities and save the changes again.

```
using (var personsContext = new PersonsContext(DbContextOptions))
{
    var him = personsContext.Persons.Find(1);
    var her = personsContext.Persons.Find(2);
    him.SpouseId = null;
    her.SpouseId = null;

    personsContext.SaveChanges(); // Add this line

    personsContext.Persons.Remove(him);
    personsContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought and tried, but without success. But you pointed me to another issue, update follows...